# How many ways of putting k disjoint paths in n x m matrix

Tags: algorithm

So I have a `n x m` matrix. I need to find out how many different ways can I put `k` disjoint paths on this matrix. Every paths fullfills these conditions:

-It starts in the first column.

-Ends in the last one.

-If the path ends on `(a,b)` for `b<m`, then the next step can only on the grid `(a',b+1)`, where `|a'-a|<=1` (meaning me move diagonally down one step, first one in the tuple is the x coordinate, second one is the y coordinate).

-I know that `n` is small (say 8), so It doesn't ruin the complexity of the algorithm much.

The obvious brute force method (recursively explore all possible options) is correct, but because `m` can be horrendously large it's no use here.

What I'm having extreme trouble with is thinking about these disjoint paths. For `k=1` things would be simple. We would associate with each element of the array the number of paths that end on it and calculate it recursively with the following formula `tab[m][n]=tab[m-1][n-1]+tab[m-1][n+1]`. But what about when `k=2`? I think that If I could tackle this problem I could easily expand it for larger `k`'s, but I'm having trouble with thinking about algorithms that aren't exponential in cost.

Comment: Is the restriction really |a-a'|<b?  i.e. when you start with b=1 you must move right, then on the next step you can move diagonally up, right or down, then on later steps you have even more freedom?

Comment: Corrected, instead of `b` it should be `1`.

Comment: Should it also be <= not <? Or perhaps == 1?

Comment: Correct yet again :) Sorry for thise missteps.

Comment: Should it be |a-a'| ==1? Because your formula doesn't account for the case |a-a'|=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to establish an algorithm which is not exponential, but at least I believe I can generalize the problem for k>=2, provided that k is less than n and n is relatively small (say 8)

Assuming we are looking at an 8 row M column matrix where M is large, and you need to fit in k paths that wiggles all the way from left towards the right.

A single column can be drawn with C(8,k) possible configurations, which max at about 70.
You should be able to further establish a 70x70 matrix, indicating each configuration can be consecutive to what other column configuration, abiding to your path rules.

The above matrix is actually a non-directional graph on 70 vertices.

The problem has now transformed to find all the M length paths in the graph.

Further edit:  if you only wish to obtain the total count of possible M column config, polynomial algorithm is possible as below:

consider the following has already been obtained:

total count of N-1 column config, where the counts are summed according to last columns configuration (e.g. 5 configs ends with config1, 46 ends with config2, etc... 28 ends with config 70). This can be expressed in an array or hashtable

you can easily derive the next array for N column config, using your 70x70 matrix.

The above therefore forms a polynomial time algo to count the total number of M Column configs. You just have to start with N=1